# Convert a pandas dataframe single column into a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

please I'm have a simple question but I can't see it answered anywhere.
My starting point is a pandas dataframe with multiple columns. I need to select one of the columns by position and eventually convert this column to a series.

```
df = pd.Dataframe(no.random.randn(20,2), columns=['a','b'])
price = df.iloc[:,[1]]  # this should give us a dataframe still
```

I tried:

```
price_series = pd.Series(price)
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `price = df.iloc[:,1]` - convert to `Series`, `price = df.iloc[:,[1]]` convert to `one column df`

Comment: oh, I didn't know that. Great, thank you!